# Xamarin Studio: Design Time Preview of AppCompat Views in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Studio on Windows and have installed various Xamarin.Android.Support Packages that backport some views. But I didn't manage to get the design time preview to work:

[image: Missing Preview]

I also installed the `Android Support Library` via the Android SDK Manager because I thought the java rendering process might only look there. But that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to get design time preview functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for design time preview for Android support packages in Xamarin currently. I've seen some work on this but from what i heard this is not going to be released without the new Roslyn compiler for Xamarin. More information about that can be found here: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2015/Jul-21.html

Comment: That's unfortunate ... Did you find any other question or source stating that this feature is not implemented? I can't believe that I am the first one to stumble over this, yet I haven't found something like a bugtracker item that I could vote on.

Comment: We all know that the designer is really bad, i think i saw some posts on some forum that someone who works at Xamarin said they where working on it, that's all i know.